# Can I generate a time series with same features as a given dataset, but add a known linear trend coefficient (not just trend strength)?

Tags: time-series, trend, synthetic-data

I want to generate data that matches features of environmental data (that is often analysed with nonparametric tests due to nonrmality, skewness etc). I want to know how to best capture any linear trend present (comparing different nonparametric and parametric methods), but to do that I want a benchmark to know what the true linear trend is. I see GRATIS is able to generate data based on features from a given dataset, but it doesn't seem to allow setting the value for a linear trend (just trend strength) - is there a way to do this?